# Project parabola onto another plane (edited)

Tags: conic-sections, projection, quadrics

I am starting with a paraboloid in the form

$$A x^{2} + B x y + C y^{2} + D x + E y + F = z$$

and a plane

$$a x + b y + c z + d = 0$$

By equating the z terms in the two equations, I have the equation of the resulting 2nd degree curve in the world coordinate frame as

$$
f = \begin{cases} A_1 x^{2} + B_1 x y + C_1 y^{2} + D_1 x + E_1 y + F_1 = 0 \\
          z = -\frac{a x + b y + d}{c}
\end{cases}
$$

The first part of "f" is the projection of the curve of intersection along the z-axis onto the x-y plane.

For the case where this curve "f" is a parabola, I am trying to find its equation as associated with a coordinate frame attached to the plane of intersection. This new frame has its z axis aligned with the plane normal, but I can choose the origin and the orientation of x axis on the plane to make the equation simpler.

[Example scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2xXA.png)
shows a parabloid with the equation:
$$ -0.05x^2-1.1y^2+0.5xy+0.5x+5=z$$ the plane is
$$0.485x-0.485y+0.728z-0.97 = 0$$

Th equation of the resultant parabola(cyan) on the x-y plane is
$$-0.036x^2+0.36xy-0.8y^2+0.85x-0.48y+2.67=0$$

I am trying to find the equation of the white parabola. I have tried projecting 4 points onto the intersection plane and fitting a parabola to it. Those two possible solutions for that are shown in green and red. As can be seen, the red one, which is the closest, doesn't quite match up to the white. I can of course pick a lot more points and try a least square solution, but I was wondering if there is a smarter way to do this.

Comment: It is recommended that you show your effort to solve this question, or at least include the origin of your question in the body of the post.

Comment: There is not necessarily a unique answer; it depends what is meant by _project_ (one plane on another).

Comment: @soupless I have updated the question with more context on what I am trying to do. Any sugessions are appreciated.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang the projection in this context is along the z-axis. I have updated the question with relevant details. Any suggessions are appreciated.

Comment: The diagram isn't clear

Comment: It seems you don't need a projection onto the $xy$ plane, but instead what you'll looking for is the equation of the intersection of the paraboloid with the intersecting plane.  Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @GeometryLover yes, that is correct. It is just that, the way I solve it now, gives the equation of this parabola in 3D as a combination of it projection on the x-y plane as well as the equation of the intersecting plane for the z coordinates.

Comment: [Here is how Wolfram Alpha plots your example paraboloid.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-0.05x%5E2-1.1y%5E2%2B0.5xy%2B0.5x%2B5%3Dz) It does not look like your picture. How did you produce the picture of your example?

Comment: The plane in your example can also be written $z = -485/728 (x - y - 2)$ (see [this calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.485x%E2%88%920.485y%2B0.728z%E2%88%920.97%3D0+solve+for+z)). If you equate the right-hand side of this with the left-hand side of the equation of the paraboloid (that is, equate the $z$ coordinates of the two surfaces), you get the equation of a hyperbola in the $x,y$ plane.

Comment: The equation $z = -\frac{a x + b y + d}{z}$ does not seem to have much to do with "equating the $z$ terms in the two equations". Its right-hand side is undefined at $z=0,$ and elsewhere it is equivalent to $z^2 = -(a x + b y + d)$, which gives two solutions for $z$ whenever $a x + b y + d < 0$ and no solutions when $a x + b y + d > 0.$ It seems to have little to do with the original plane, which never has two $z$ coordinates at any choice of $(x,y)$ coordinates. What do you think it represents?

Comment: @DavidK My plot is only in the region of x within (-5,5), as that is where the intersection with the plane occurs. equating the z terms of the paraboloid and the plane is exactly how I obtain the equation I mentioned above. The resulting surface of intersection, which in the example is as you mentioned a hyperbola, is obtained as a combination of two equations. The problem is still to get the equation of this curve on the plane of intersection. 
z=−(ax+by+d)/z is a typo, it should be z=-(ax+by+d)/c. I will edit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define $\mathbf{r} = [x, y, z]^T $ as the position vector.  Then the equation

$ z= A x^2 + B x y + C y^2 + D x + E y + F $

can be written as

$ \mathbf{r}^T \mathbf{Q r} + \mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{r} + c = 0 \hspace{12pt}(1)$

where

$\mathbf{Q} = \begin{bmatrix} A && \frac{1}{2} B && 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} B && C && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\mathbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix} D , E , -1 \end{bmatrix}^T $

$c = F $

And the intersecting plane can be written as $ \mathbf{n}^T (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_0) = 0 $ where

$\mathbf{n} = \begin{bmatrix} a, b, c \end{bmatrix}^T$, and $\mathbf{r_0}$ is any point on the plane, satisfying $\mathbf{n}^T \mathbf{r_0} = - d $

Next, write the vector equation of the plane,

$ \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r_0} + u_1 \mathbf{v_1} + u_2 \mathbf{v_2}\hspace{12pt} (2) $

where $\mathbf{v_1, v_2}$ are two unit mutually orthogonal vectors are orthogonal to vector $\mathbf{n}$.

Equation (2) can be written compactly as

$ \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r_0} + \mathbf{V u} \hspace{12pt} (3) $

where $\mathbf{V} = [ \mathbf{v_1}, \mathbf{v_2} ] $ and $ \mathbf{u} = [u_1, u_2]^T$

Now substitute (3) into (1), to obtain,

$ ( \mathbf{r_0} + \mathbf{V u} )^T \mathbf{Q}(\mathbf{r_0} + \mathbf{V u}) + \mathbf{b}^T (\mathbf{r_0} + \mathbf{V u}) + c = 0 $

Expanding,

$ \mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{V}^T \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{V u} + \mathbf{u}^T (2 \mathbf{V}^T \mathbf{Q r_0} + \mathbf{V}^T \mathbf{b} ) + \mathbf{r_0}^T \mathbf{Q r_0} + \mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{r_0}+ c = 0 \hspace{12pt} (4)$

This is the equation of the intersection between the quadric and the plane.

It specifies the relation between the coordinates $u_1$ and $u_2$ in the $\mathbf{r_0 ,V}$ coordinate frame.

The next step is to diagonalize $\mathbf{V}^T \mathbf{Q V} $ so that,

$\mathbf{V}^T \mathbf{Q V} = \mathbf{ R D R}^T $

where $R$ is a $2 \times 2$ rotation matrix and $D $ is a $2 \times 2 $ diagonal matrix.

The above intersection will be a parabola if and only if $\mathbf{D}$ has exactly one diagonal entry equal to $0$.  And we can assume that this zero entry is $D_{22}$.

Define the vector $\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{R}^T \mathbf{u} $, then equation (4) in terms of $w$ becomes

$ \mathbf{w}^T D \mathbf{w} + \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{g} + h = 0 \hspace{12pt} (5)$

where $ \mathbf{g} = \mathbf{R}^T ( 2 \mathbf{V}^T \mathbf{Q r_0} + \mathbf{V}^T \mathbf{b} ) $ and $ h = \mathbf{r_0}^T \mathbf{Q r_0} +\mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{r_0}+ c $

Remember that $D_{22} = 0 $, and let $D_{11} = a , \mathbf{g} = [g_1, g_2]^T$ and $\mathbf{w} = [x, y]^T $ (not to be confused with the $x$ and $y$ in the world coordinate frame $Oxyz$ ), then equation (5) reads,

$ a x^2 + g_1 x + g_2 y + h = 0 $

For this to be a parabola, we can assume that $g_2 \ne 0$ and $a \ne 0$, then by completing the square, we have

$ a (x + \dfrac{g_1}{2 a} )^2 + g_2 y + h - \dfrac{g_1^2}{4 a} = 0 $

so that,

$ y = -\dfrac{a}{g_2} (x + \dfrac{g_1}{2a} )^2 + \dfrac{1}{g_2} ( \dfrac{g_1^2}{4a} - h ) $

And this specifies the $y$ coordinate as a function of $x$ coordinate in the $\mathbf{r_0},\mathbf{W}$  coordinate frame.

To summarize, at the end we will have two axes given by the columns of the matrix $\mathbf{W} =\mathbf{VR}$. Let these two columns be $\mathbf{w_1} $ and $\mathbf{w_2} $, then the parabola of intersection is given explicitly (and parametrically) by

$\mathbf{r} =\mathbf{r_0} + x \mathbf{w_1} + y \mathbf{w_2} =  \mathbf{r_1}  + t \mathbf{w_1} + \alpha t^2 \mathbf{w_2} \hspace{12pt} (6) $

where the $\alpha = -\dfrac{a}{g_2}$ and $\mathbf{r_1} $ is the vertex of the parabola, given by,

$ \mathbf{r_1} = \mathbf{r_0} + x_0 \mathbf{w_1} + y_0 \mathbf{w_2} \hspace{12pt} (7)$

with $x_0 = - \dfrac{g_1}{2a}, y_0 = \dfrac{1}{g_2} ( \dfrac{g_1^2}{4a} - h ) $

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the help! For my purpose equation 4 is all I needed, so I only verified until that point. I believe there is a typo in your expansion leading up to equation 4. But the equation before that gives the correct result.

Comment: Thanks.  I've corrected the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Any conic section (through 5 or less constants in plane C) projects to another conic section when projected onto an arbitrary inclined plane ( formed spanned with 3 constants in plane P).

This is determined by functions of the dihedral angle between P and C.